# R: how to include a character between two repeted items in R?

Tags: r, vector

I am new to R and have a few questions about vectors.

I need help creating a vector n containing two copies of vector x, separated by a 0.

I wrote the following code, but missing the ´0´part:

```
x<-c(3,10,30)


n=rep(x, times=2)

n
```

In addition, how to check if the content of two vectors is equal?
And finally, how do I check for the length of a vector?

Comment: try this `c(x,0,x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabrina- welcome to stackoverflow!

1c: If you just need a 0 between two vectors, you can use the `c()` function to combine multiple objects together. In this case, we can make two copies of x with a 0 in-between them like so - `c(x,0,x)`

2: `R` lets you check whether two things are equal in multiple ways. It sounds like your professor wants you to use the `==` approach, which checks if each element of two things are the same. As the next question notes though, doing that when they aren't the same length is possibly problematic - which element is the start, etc. Just something to be aware of. You can use if two things are identical though with `identical()`

3: There is a function you can use for this. `length()` tells you how many elements are in an object. Just for fun, we can the `==` approach here to see if the lengths are equal (we know that `R` should tell use FALSE of course)

If this answer addresses your question, please hit the 'checkmark' next to it to accept it as answered. Thanks!

```
x<-c(3,10,30)
x

m=rep(x, each=2)
m

n=rep(x, times=2)
n

# question 1c
n <- c(x, 0, x)
n

# Question 2: Is the content of m equal to the content of n?
n == m

# Question 3: How can you check the length of both vectors?
length(n)
length(m)

length(n) == length(m)
```

Comment: If this answer addresses your question, please hit the 'checkmark' next to it to accept it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Dear BHudson, Thank you so much for your help and for clarifying everything and for including the code. That's so kind of you and it is really appreciated! And I'm really happy I joined this forum. I hope you see my answer because you were a life saver! :) All the best, Sabrina

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for the kind comment :)